# Failing to Update a result set from msql table

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a problem with updating a result set given by mssql.

I want to update a column (initial_deposit) in the table (**createaccount** with a primary key  **id**) with a new value that is found after adding  (**initial** and the **AmountDeposited**). **AmountDeposited** is entered as a double on a textField named (**textFieldamount**) and initial is also a double value from the result set.

I am getting an error. (Result Set not updatable (referenced table has no primary keys).

This result set must come from a statement that was created with a result set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE.)

Here is my code

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/STATTER_BANK";
String user = "root";
String password = "";
double amountDeposited = Double.parseDouble(textFieldamount.getText());

public void theQuery {
    String query1 = "SELECT initial_deposit FROM createaccount"+"WHERE id=1";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        PreparedStatement stt = con.prepareStatement(query1, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

       ResultSet rs = stt.executeQuery();

       while (rs.next()) {
           double initial = rs.getDouble("initial_deposit");
           rs.updateDouble( "initial_deposit", initial + amountDeposited);
           rs.updateRow();
       }
    } catch (Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer.
[similar question perhaps it is the same one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124427/resultset-update-row-is-not-working)
Changing   ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE with ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE should work.

Comment: You should add that as a comment, not an answer. If a question is a duplicate, you should flag it as such.

Comment: @RealSkeptic i don't have that much points (reputation) for commenting

Comment: The solution to that is to write proper answers, and earn those required points. You are not far away from that. An improper answer is not the way to go.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yeah got that.  I have recently started SO .

Comment: i have tried with ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE still getting the same error

Comment: do you have primary key in your table ?id is your primary key?
can you show your schema?